# I need help to find some good videos to learn calculus I 2 3

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Calculus 1 2 3?
What is the best web page and YouTube channel to learn calculus from scratch without memorizing formulas and other stuff? I want to make sense of definition and other stuff without memorizing like machine. There are tons of symbols line Δ,∇, ∂ , ε , λ, φ, →, Ξ, Π, ∀, ∪, ℵ, ∪, η, and etc.. I want to know their applications, and understand  them deeply, because I try to do research by myself they appear everywhere. I don't understand and stop to read. It is like other language. My teacher teaches like a machine; he just tells us just memorize them. There are tons of videos but I don't know what to chose. I need a professional from here to guide which ones are best.

And what are all integral methods that exist  like trigonometry sb. Gaussian method and Etc.. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Khan Academy is pretty good.